# SQL Server Trigger Error Message

Tags: sql-server, triggers

This is the error I am getting:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_UpdateFolio, Line 361
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've run up and down this code over and over for hours now. What am I not seeing? Any help would be appreciated. I've been working on this for a few days now, and this is pretty much the one thing I need working in order to get this project done.

```
-- 2. Write a trigger named tr_UpdateFolio  that will be invoked when the Folio table 'status' 
-- field ONLY (column update) is changed.
ALTER TRIGGER tr_UpdateFolio ON FOLIO--switch alter back to create
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE([Status])
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Status char(1)
        DECLARE @FolioID smallint
        DECLARE @CheckinDate smalldatetime
        DECLARE @Nights tinyint
        DECLARE @CurrentDate smalldatetime = '7/27/2016 2:00:00 PM'

        SELECT 
            @Status = i.Status, 
            @FolioID = i.FolioID,  
            @CheckinDate = i.CheckinDate, 
            @Nights = i.Nights
        FROM 
            INSERTED i

        -- If Folio status is updated to 'C' for Checkout, trigger two different Insert statements to 
        -- (1) INSERT in the Billing table, the amount for the total lodging cost as BillingCategoryID1
        -- -  (normally the FolioRate * number of nights stay, but you must  also factor in any late checkout fees*). 
        -- *Checkout time is Noon on the checkout date. Guest is given a one hour 
        -- grace period to check out. After 1PM (but before 4PM), a 50% surcharge is added to the FolioRate. After 4PM, an 
        -- additional full night's FolioRate is applied. You can recycle code from A7  (part 5), but note it's not the exact same 
        -- function - we only need the late charge (if any).

        IF @Status = 'C'
           SET @Nights = 1

        --@CurrentDate may need to switch back to getdate()
        IF DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CheckinDate + @Nights, @CurrentDate) >= 16
            SET @Nights = @Nights + 1
        ELSE IF DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CheckinDate + @Nights, @CurrentDate) >= 13
            SET @Nights = @Nights + .5

        UPDATE FOLIO
        SET Nights = @Nights
        WHERE FolioID = @FolioID

        INSERT INTO BILLING (FolioID, BillingCategoryID, BillingDescription, BillingAmount, BillingItemQty, BillingItemDate)
        VALUES (25, 1, 'Room', dbo.GetRackRate(11, @CurrentDate) * @Nights, 1, @CurrentDate)

        -- (2) The second INSERT statement in the same trigger will insert the Lodging Tax* - as a separate entry in the 
        -- Billing table for tax on lodging (BillingCategoryID2).  *Use the dbo.GetRoomTaxRate function from A7 to determine 
        -- the Lodging Tax.  
        INSERT INTO BILLING (FolioID, BillingCategoryID, BillingDescription, BillingAmount, BillingItemQty, BillingItemDate)
        VALUES (25, 2, 'Lodging Tax', dbo.GetRoomTaxRate(20), 1, @CurrentDate)
END
GO

-- 3. Write a trigger named tr_GenerateBill that will be invoked when an entry is INSERTED in to the Billing 
-- table. If BillngCategoryID is 2 (for testing purposes only) then call the function dbo.ProduceBill (from A7).

ALTER TRIGGER tr_GenerateBill ON BILLING
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @FolioID smallint
DECLARE @BillingCategoryID smallint

SELECT @FolioID = i.FolioID, @BillingCategoryID = i.BillingCategoryID
FROM INSERTED i

IF @BillingCategoryID = 2
SELECT * FROM dbo.ProduceBill(@FolioID)
END
GO
```

dbo.producebill should be fine, but the error occurs when I try to run this block

```
-- 4A. Assume today is (July 27, 2016 at 2PM)*. Anita is due to check out today (from Part 1 above).
-- Write an Update Statement to change the status of her Folio to 'CheckedOut.
-- (Be careful to include a WHERE clause so ONLY here folio is updated).
-- Note: This should automatically invoke tr_UpdateFolio above (factoring in the late charge),
-- which automatically invokes tr_GenerateBill  above, and calls dbo.ProduceBill , and produces a bill.

UPDATE FOLIO
SET [Status] = 'C'
WHERE ReservationID = 5020
```

I'm going nuts trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. You are assuming there will only ever be a single row inserted at a time. This is not how triggers work in sql server. They fire once per operation, not once per row. You need to make this set based logic. You also might consider getting rid of those scalar functions, they are notoriously poor performers.

Comment: I'm not seeing where I need to fix this. I'm just learning Triggers, so I'm still a bit shaky when it comes to this.

Comment: Both of your ENTIRE triggers are designed around the concept of a single row. They both need to be completely rebuilt to handle sets.

Comment: How would I even begin doing that? Sorry, I'm just fresh at this still and am getting anxious about this not working is all. I've been pounding my head against the wall for a good while now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the easier one (tr_GenerateBill). This one is a little odd for sure. You have a select statement in an insert trigger. This means that when you insert a row you are expecting it to return row(s). This is not the typical behavior of an insert but you can work with it.

If you insert 3 rows and only 2 of them have a BillingCategoryID of 2 what should the trigger do? What does that table valued function look like?

This is kind of a guess but you should be able to rewrite that entire trigger to something along these lines.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_GenerateBill ON BILLING
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM inserted i
    cross apply dbo.ProduceBill(i.FolioID) pb
    where i.BillingCategoryID = 2
END
```

Your second trigger is more challenging. It is not totally clear what you are trying to do here but I think this is pretty close.

```
UPDATE f
set Nights = case when DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CheckinDate + i.Nights, @CurrentDate) >= 16 then 2 else 1 end --adding .5 to a tiny int is pointless. It will ALWAYS be the same value.
from inserted i
join Folio f on f.FolioID = i.FolioID


INSERT INTO BILLING (FolioID, BillingCategoryID, BillingDescription, BillingAmount, BillingItemQty, BillingItemDate)
Select i.FolioID
    , 1
    , 'Room'
    , dbo.GetRackRate(11, @CurrentDate) * case when DATEDIFF(HOUR, @CheckinDate + i.Nights, @CurrentDate) >= 16 then 2 else 1 end, 1, @CurrentDate)
from inserted i

INSERT INTO BILLING (FolioID, BillingCategoryID, BillingDescription, BillingAmount, BillingItemQty, BillingItemDate)
select i.FolioID
    , 2
    , 'Lodging Tax'
    , dbo.GetRoomTaxRate(20), 1, @CurrentDate)
from inserted i
```

Comment: In the second trigger, I'm trying to add a 50% surcharge with that .5. The comments right before the IF @Status = 'C' explain what needs to happen.

Comment: I made those changes, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I've been fighting this for the last two hours. What am I not seeing?

Comment: You state that you want to add a 50% surcharge but you are using a tinyint datatype and adding .5 If you want to add .5 you need a numeric datatype instead. When you add .5 to any tinyint it will always become the same value because it is integer math. As for the error....there is no subquery here so I don't see how that error is possible. Unless it is in one of the scalar functions. Can you post the contents of those?

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for pointing out the issue with my answer.  I thought for sure that's how that syntax worked but then I tried it on my local machine and it just set it to the value of the last row; not what I expected at all.